# Change to Eclipse project library is reverted for rest of the team

Tags: c++, eclipse, git, project

We have a team of several members using Eclipse for a C & C++ application that we commit the make files it generates as part of the package build. I have added and committed a library to the project then we decide against using it. So I remove it from my project and commit the change to git for the rest of the team. When anyone else pulls the change their Eclipse reverts the removal to the .cproject file preventing the removal of the unwanted library, include paths, and toolchain paths. The only thing that seems to work is to blow away the project metadata and re-import the project, which is a hassle.

How do I easily get everyone else's Eclipse to accept the removal and stop adding it back in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from not committing the .metadata folder. Eclipse keeps a backup of the project somewhere in there and continually changes these file making it unreasonable to commit to source control.
The only thing I've found to always work is to delete the project from the workspace, but do not remove the files, and import the updated project after pulling the updates from source control.

Answer (score -1):

You and your team may not be able or willing to do this, but it is easier to not check in IDE specific files at all and allow a build tool plugin like Maven or Gradle to handle the project structure and classpath.  This is how I've worked with team members for years without experiencing this problem.

There is quite a bit of a paradigm shift doing this, and depending on the flexibility of your project it may not be feasible.

***Edit:***
I noticed you are of the C persuasion.  I don't recommend Maven, but consider Gradle.
https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/native_software.html

Comment: Will that also affect the generated make files?

Comment: Yes, like I said, it is a complete build paradigm shift.  But in the enterprise and open source world you typically want to avoid checking in IDE specific stuff because developers use whatever IDE best suits them.  This is especially a problem with file paths in the project.  Everyone has to be on the same type of OS (Windows vs Linux) with the same directory structure or else it breaks.  Keeping IDE agnostic is the best bet in the long run.

But that may or may not be a problem you need to tackle.  Your call.

Comment: We all work off of the same VM base image so no worries about being IDE agnostic which is what lead to this issue. Our Eclipse version is Luna (4.4.0) if that helps any.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to try is to close the project (or maybe even Eclipse) and run the git pull outside of Eclipse.  If your workspace and git project are one in the same then it might work for you. Let me know if that works and I will update my answer.

Comment: Nope, tried that first. Like the question states Eclipse will revert changes made by git once it is opened.